# F key not working

Tags: blender-osm

I am watching this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1sjHg4KtyY, and I'm at this part of it, https://youtu.be/f1sjHg4KtyY?t=762, but I dont understand what they do, and when I press F, nothing happens.

Comment: The F key is to fill a face or create an edge from the selected vertices. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/make_face_edge.html#make-edge-face) is the section in the Blender manual explaining what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The F key is used to fill a face. You need to have enough vertices selected to create a face, this usually works by having the vertices surround a particular empty space. If you want to fill only part of it, you can extrude an edge from a vertex by pressing E and then merging it to another vertex by pressing M.